# How to check when data changes in component by itself with vue js?

Tags: javascript, methods, vue.js, components

I have method that changes data in itself, simple example:

```
Vue.component('component', {
  template: '#component',
  data: function () {
    return {
      dataToBeWatched: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change: function (e) {
      var that = this;
      setTimeOut(function() {
        that.dataToBeWatched = 'data changed';
      }, 2000);
    },
    makeSmthWhenDataChanged: function () {
      // ajax request when dataToBeWatched changed or when dataToBeWatched isn't empty
    }
  }
});
```

How to create such watcher using correct methods vue js?
Or I need to use props watching it in component?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Vue components can have a `watch` property which is an object. The object keys need to be the name of the prop or data that needs to be watched, and the  value is a function that is invoked when the data changes.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

```
Vue.component('component', {
  template: '#component',
  data: function () {
    return {
      dataToBeWatched: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change: function (e) {
      var that = this;
      setTimeOut(function() {
        that.dataToBeWatched = 'data changed';
      }, 2000);
    },
    makeSmthWhenDataChanged: function () {
      // ajax request when dataToBeWatched changed or when dataToBeWatched isn't empty
    }
  },
  watch: {
      dataToBeWatched: function(val) {
          //do something when the data changes.
          if (val) {
              this.makeSmthWhenDataChanged();
          }
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it should be simple!